# Amazon AWS Transfer Family Authentication SFTP error

Tags: amazon-web-services

I just created an AWS Transfer server with users is Secret with appropriate roles and policies. When I test the user against 'Test' feature under the server 'Actions', I get a 200 Success.

```
{
    "Response": "{}",
    "StatusCode": 200,
    "Message": "",
    "Url": "https://oxf21gni8k.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/prod/servers/s-*******/users/user/config"
}
```

But when I connect from the actual client, with the same username/password and source IP, I get-

```
$ sftp -o PubkeyAuthentication=no user@s-*********.server.transfer.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
user@s-********.server.transfer.us-east-1.amazonaws.com's password:
Permission denied, please try again.
```

Looking at CloudWatch logs, I'm seeing an AUTH ERROR with no apparent explanation-

```
ERRORS AUTH_FAILURE Method=password User=user Message= SourceIP= x.x.x.x
```

(Deidentified source IP for privacy). Any idea what might cause this?

Comment: If you use an incorrect password, does it provide the same error message? If so, then it would appear that the wrong username or password is being used.

Comment: It provides the same error message with incorrect password. I just reset the password and typed/copied it multiple times with no luck. Its weird the 'Message' value is empty. (Was expecting something like 'Message=Incorrect Password') Not sure what the error is (if not incorrect password).

Comment: And you changed `user@` to the appropriate username? I wonder if it would work any better if you used an FTP client (eg Filezilla).

Comment: Correct, used `user@`. I'll try other clients.

Comment: Used Winscp. Same error of 'Access Denied'

Comment: What do you mean by "used `user@`"? Did you [create an SFTP user](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/transfer/latest/userguide/create-user.html) with the username of `user`?

Comment: Yep, created a `SFTP/user` secret and tried logging in as that user. Weird thing is when I use the same user/password and test it against the API gateway on the AWS console, I get a 200 SUCCESS response.

Answer (score 0):

Create IAM role with Transfer usecase and, add AmazonS3FullAccess policy.

On your AWS Family Transfer configuration, add a new user.

[image]

Generate ssh key on your machine: `ssh-keygen -P "" -f transfer-key`

And, copy the content of the `transfer-key.pub` file and, past in SSH public key:

[image]

Install sftp and try:

```
sftp -i <private_key>  <user>@<created_endpoint_in_aws_transfer_family>
```

[image]

Example: `sftp -i transfer-key.pem  user@endpoint`

`transfer-key.pem` is the private key you generated above.

You can also test your connexion with Filezilla.